# Confusion with auto assignment with list initialization syntax

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm just now able to use C++11 for the first time at my job and I'm learning as I go. I have read [GotW #94](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) and I'm trying to adopt his recommendation for using `auto` when declaring local variables instead of explicitly stating the type.

Given this, I have the following code:

```
class foo
{
};

int main()
{
    auto f = foo const*{nullptr};
}
```

My assignment in main does not compile and fails with:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:13:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
     auto f = foo const*{nullptr};
                  ^
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. What am I doing wrong here?

(My sample is [on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d73a5e3ae64bb3e)).

Comment: Nothing wrong with the old-fashioned, easier to understand: `foo const *f = nullptr ;`.

Comment: @jliv902 I tend to agree (simply because that's what I'm used to), but there is nothing forcing one to initialize it to NULL if you don't use the syntax he recommends (I kind of like that as a general practice, especially with pointers)

Comment: `auto f = static_cast<foo const*>(nullptr);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the functional notation for type conversion, the type name must be a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* (*§5.2.3 [expr.type.conv]*), which basically means a type name consisting of a single word.

```
unsigned int a = unsigned int(42);
```

fails too, and there's no type inference or list initialization involved.

In my opinion, using `auto` in your example amounts to obfuscation. Just use

```
foo const* f{nullptr};
```

If you must use `auto`, create an alias

```
using foo_const_p = foo const*;
auto f = foo_const_p{nullptr};
```

Comment: Wow, the old style C++03 example you gave at first really puts things into perspective. I agree with the obfuscation statement, I didn't realize the rules would be so complex after reading Herb's article. I think I'll stick with the version that doesn't use auto. No benefit.

Answer (score 1):

The `T(x)` and `T{x}` syntax don't allow arbitrary types to be used for `T`. Allowing it would make the syntax rather complicated in some cases. If you *really* want to use `auto` here, you'll need to wrap the type, like so:

```
template <typename T> using id = T;
auto f = id<foo const*>{nullptr};
```

but personally, I don't really think it's useful here.

To be more specific, the C++ syntax defines the grammatical constructs as

```
postfix-expression:
  ...
  simple-type-specifier ( expression-listopt )
  ...
  simple-type-specifier braced-init-list
  ...

simple-type-specifier:
  ::opt nested-name-specifieropt type-name
  ::opt nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id
  char
  char16_t
  char32_t
  wchar_t
  bool
  short
  int
  long
  signed
  unsigned
  float
  double
  void
  auto
  decltype-specifier

type-name:
  class-name
  enum-name
  typedef-name
  simple-template-id
```

The syntax to allow arbitrary types is part of the `type-id` rule, which is not one of the options of `simple-type-specifier`, but is one of the possibilities for the `template-argument` rule within a `simple-template-id`, which is why a template alias is a valid workaround.

Comment: What do you mean by *"arbitrary types"*? Herb uses simple core types in his example. Does that not apply to pointer-versions of these types?

Comment: @RobertDailey No, it doesn't. Nor does it allow, for example, `long long`. It only allows types that follow specific syntactic rules, and using a template alias like this lets you work around it if needed.